# Simple stresses and strains

Tags: forces, pressure, stress-strain

Why nature of stress in a state of stress at a ponit is as same as applied force even the stree is opposite to the applied load

Answer (score 2):

Stress (being a tensor rather than a vector)  is not the same thing as force, so the notion of being in the "same direction" or "opposite direction" to the applied load does not mean anything.